# Get current language abbreviation (same as the localisation bundle name)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm trying to get the localization abbreviation for the current language.

I'm doing this:

```
[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode]
```

Using that line I can get this results: `en`, `es`, `fr`

the problem I have is that if my iphone is in UK-english I get the same `en`and not `en-GB` as it should be.

I also tried `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` but then I get `en-US` for us-english or `zh-Hant-US` for Chinese but in this case I don't need the last part.

I'm using it because I need to manually get some resources from localisation bundles which automatically are named as follow: `en.lpoj`, `en-GB.lpoj`, `zh-Hant.lproj`.

Do Anybody know how could I get the current language with the same format as the localisation bundle names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue you should use:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations]
```

it gets the language based on what your app supports.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
[NSLocale currentLocale].localeIdentifier
```

This will give you `en_GB`, but you can change the `_` to `-`

Good luck!

Comment: it returns "en_US" for us-english, but the localisation bundle for us-english is named "en-lproj" .... I just cannot remove always the _ or replace it because I can't know if it is necessary or not

Comment: I found the solution, I posted it here if you are interested on it @ajpallares